# Why doesn't pytesseract recognize any text in this image?

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, python-tesseract, east-text-detector

I have this image [input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccl6t.png) on which I am attempting to apply text detection and ocr,
however even after preprocessing (binary thresholding etc) pytesseract doesn't return any output. The purpose of text detection is to improve the ocr output, I'm not too concerned with obtaining bounding boxes.

Here is my code below:

```
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

grey = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(grey,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

image = pytesseract.image_to_data(thresh1, output_type=Output.DICT)
image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
```

Inspecting the results there is none to nonsensical output, is there anyway to improve this?

Comment: take a look at: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html). ... The answer is: with tesseract you need to preprocess your image. at least it need to be in black and white.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, although my image has been preprocessed and is in black and white, which was achived by the code posted

Comment: What is output_type=Output.DICT?

Comment: its stores the output of image_to_data in a dictionary

Comment: Then, why are you trying to apply an openCV function (matrix array) to a dictionary? What is exactly what do you want? it is to draw the rectangles (in the image) for each word/number?

Comment: `pytesseract.image_to_data()` returns these keys: `['level', 'page_num', 'block_num', 'par_num', 'line_num', 'word_num', 'left', 'top', 'width', 'height', 'conf', 'text']` you have to use  the values in `'left', 'top', 'width', 'height'` to draw each rentangle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('ccl6t.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'k:\Tesseract\tesseract.exe' #need change!
grey = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(grey,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imwrite('tresh.png', thresh1)
words = pytesseract.image_to_data(thresh1, lang='eng',config='--psm 3 --oem 1 ')
print(str(words))
```

Comment: I tried your code, but still don't get the expected output. I'd like to locate the text in the image and extract/identify the names